# how to add content in user control dynamically in window application?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, window

this program i will try so many time but it can not perform properly so please give me proper advice..
how to solve this problem..
and how to add the content dynamically in the usercontrol..
here contentcontrol is usercontrol and how to use it dynamically and how to give content dynamicalyy...

```
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Content = "click here";
        b.Height = 200;
        b.Width = 200;
        DesignerCanvas.Children.Add(b);
        DesignerCanvas.UpdateLayout();
        Selector.SetIsSelected(b as Control,true);
        ContentControl cc = new ContentControl();
        cc.children.add(b);
```

Comment: It is not clear at all what you are trying to do. Could you please clarify what you expect the provided code to accomplish? By the way, you generally don't want to manipulate the UI this way in XAML

Comment: Please learn data templates and how to use them. This is meant to be done via ItemsControl (if there are multiple buttons needed), otherwise DataTemplate itself will sort it.

Answer (score 4):

Content Control Represents a container control with a single child element.

Read from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

Generally a UserControl provides the base class for defining a new control.

IF you have defined a ContentControl in XAML, and if you want to add some controls say Button,

**XAML:**

```
<ContentControl x:Name="container">
</ContentControl>
```

**Code:**

```
Button btn = new Button { Content = "test" };
container.Content = btn;
```

Comment: This sounds right, but I'm not sure because the question is so confusing!. Regardless, could you add a little explanation (perhaps explaining the proper use of a content control)?

Comment: @LordTakkera Modified

Comment: Thanks! +1 for what (I think :) ) is the right answer

Comment: While I won't downvote this, I have to say, we shouldn't encourage this path of coding where you're adding view items from code-behind. This is going to set a bad example for this user and he won't learn the proper way of doing this.

Comment: @Maverik What if it is a dynamic control?

Comment: @Sajeetharan define dynamic? there's hardly a time when you can't apply mvvm to do your bidding